# Linq code not working properly

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, c#-4.0

I have written the following code in order to combine column values  "lblJurisdiction" of all those rows where checkbox is checked(true) in a grid view

```
if (grdView.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (GridViewRow row in grdView.Rows)
    {
        CheckBox chkbox = row.FindControl("chkbox") as CheckBox;
        Label lblJurisdiction = row.FindControl("lblJurisdiction") as Label;
        bool saveThis = chkbox.Checked;
        if (saveThis == true)
        {
            List<String> Items = new List<String>();
            Items.Add(lblJurisdiction.Text);
            Items.Sort();
            List<string> Unique = Items.Distinct().ToList();
            string ReplacedJurisdiction = string.Join(",", Unique.ToArray());
            hdnJurisdiction.Value = ReplacedJurisdiction;
        }
    }
}
```

For e.g grid view contains

- [true] [Alabama] [ some value]
- [true] [Alaska] [ some value]
- [false] [New York] [ some value]
- [false] [California] [ some value]

Now the hidden field should contain Alabama, Alaska
It is combining only one i.e Alaska ...

Comment: We're not psychic.

Comment: I have just asked this question in order to fix the issue which is the job of stackover flow devolepers.

Comment: No.  You are on a free web site asking people to give up their time and help you for free.  There is no **job** here.  A bit of humility will take you a long way.  As will providing complete information in your question.

Comment: This is not our job! We are helping you! @Nida

Comment: Where is the LINQ code? That's just a `foreach` loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should change your variables scope! You should declare your list outside `foreach` loop and set the value after you have done calculation. I've also changed your code to match common naming and coding conventions in C#.

```
if (grdView.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    var states = new List<string>();
    foreach (GridViewRow row in grdView.Rows)
    {
        var chkbox = row.FindControl("chkbox") as CheckBox;
        if (chkbox.Checked)
        {
            var lblJurisdiction = row.FindControl("lblJurisdiction") as Label;
            states.Add(lblJurisdiction.Text);
        }
    }
    hdnJurisdiction.Value = string.Join(", ", states.Distinct().OrderBy(x => x));
}
```

Comment: A better choice would be to actually use LINQ, select all the label texts then use Join. This will avoid creating a separate list

Answer (score 1):

You should concatenated the strings, now you are overwrite them in your hidden field

```
if(hdnJurisdiction.Value.Length > 0 && ReplacedJurisdiction != "")
   hdnJurisdiction.Value += ", ";

hdnJurisdiction.Value += ReplacedJurisdiction;
```

Answer (score 0):

The original code doesn't use LINQ at all. A LINQ query to select the labels of all checked rows could be this:

```
var labels= grdView.Rows.OfType<GridViewRow>() 
               .Where(row=>(row.FindControl("chkbox") as CheckBox)?.Checked)
               .Select(row=>(row.FindControl("lblJurisdiction") as Label)?.Text)
               .Distinct()
               .OrderBy(x=>x);
```

or this, in query form:

```
var labels=(from row in grdView.Rows.OfType<GridViewRow>()
            let chkbox = row.FindControl("chkbox") as CheckBox
            let label=row.FindControl("lblJurisdiction") as Label
            where chkbox.Checked            
            select label.Text)
           .Distinct().OrderBy(x=>x);
```

Once you have all the labels, you can join them:

```
var text=String.Join(labels);
```